# How to retrieve entity names in CRM 2016

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

In our solution, we are building HTTP/ODATA requests dynamically.

For example, we will build a URL that looks like this:

```
[http://org....api/v8.1/]accounts(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001)/primarycontactid?$select=fullname
```

**How do we dynamically get a list of all the entities such as 'accounts'?**

In 2011, we would simply execute against LeadSet/AccountSet/etcSet, **what is the strategy in 2016?**

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if there is some "language" trick (obviously the name of the set is just plural name in english of the entity, but that's not good enough for me), so I it like that - simply call webAPI metadata:

```
http://[crmurl]/api/data/v8.2/EntityDefinitions?$select=EntitySetName,LogicalName&$filter=LogicalName eq 'account'
```

result is the following:

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://[crmurl]/api/data/v8.2/$metadata#EntityDefinitions(EntitySetName,LogicalName)","value":[
    {
      "EntitySetName":"accounts","LogicalName":"account","MetadataId":"70816501-edb9-4740-a16c-6a5efbc05d84"
    }
  ]
}
```

So you get the idea. Of course you can simply skip the `$filter` part and simply get list of all set names and cache them somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach would be to generate the plural name from the singular name.

As far as I understand, the rules to pluralize entity names in the Web API v8+ are:

- ends with s, x, z, ch, or sh: add 'es'
- ends with y: remove 'y', add 'ies'
- else: add 's'

Here is a JavaScript function that I use for this:

```
function pluralName (name) {
    var plural = '';
    if (name != null && typeof(name) == 'string') {
        var len = name.length;
        var lastChar = len > 0 ? name.slice(-1) : '';
        var last2Chars = len > 1 ? name.slice(-2) : '';

        if (lastChar == 's' || lastChar == 'x' || lastChar == 'z' || last2Chars == 'ch' || last2Chars == 'sh') {
            plural = name + 'es';
        }
        else if (lastChar == 'y') {
            //strip off last character and add suffix
            plural = name.substr(0, len - 1) + 'ies';
        }
        else {
            plural = name + 's';
        }
    }
    return plural;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1.To get all the entities available in your crm:

```
https://<your org name>.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/
```

2.To get all the records metadata information (Retrieve Multiple Records):

```
https://<your org name>.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/accounts?
```

3.To get the specific record email address information (Retrieve Single Record). What ever we chose the attributes in the select clause, we can get those attributes information in the result:

```
https://<your org name>.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/accounts?$select=emailaddress1&$filter=accountid eq <GUID goes here>
```

4.To get entire metadata information in the CRM:

```
https://<your org name>.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/EntityDefinitions
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want the entities list, you can simply query and parser the root of the service like this:

> https://contoso.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.1/

If you want the fields too, you can do this:

> https://contoso.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.1/$metadata

Comment: You can check the list of all entity sets using this technique, but you don't have a mapping there, which EntitySet is related to which entity. Of course by looking at it you know, that "accounts" is entity set for "account", but you should have also some algorithm to be sure of that