# How to enable change tracking for ALL entities in Dynamics 365?

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I am trying to replicate Dynamics 365 in an Azure SQL database (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/replicate-data-microsoft-azure-sql-database#create-an-export-profile).

This requires me to enable "change tracking" on ~800 entities. Is there a way to do this programmatically or will I have to enable it manually for each entity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not find a plugin in XrmToolBox to achieve this.

Better to write a console app which will retrieve all the entities using [RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29694213/7920473), then iterate through each Entity in the retrieved Metadata collection & update back by setting the `EntityMetadata.ChangeTrackingEnabled` property.

Sample snippet from [this reference](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/216264):

```
UpdateEntityRequest updateBankAccountRequest = new UpdateEntityRequest
{
     Entity = BankAccountEntity,
     ChangeTrackingEnabled = true //or false here
};

_serviceProxy.Execute(updateBankAccountRequest);
```

You can use web api also. [Read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43266201/7920473).

Comment: ChangeTrackingEnabled property is no longer working. I am not able to get it resolved in code.

Comment: @sdg ask a new question and share the error message

Answer (score 1):

A C# program exists on git as a plugin For XRMToolbox. The freely available, Cobalt's "**[Bulk Update Entity Change Tracking](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/Cobalt.XrmToolbox.EntityUpdater/)**" Allows for the user to update the change tracking property on entities in bulk. it was released about 2 months after the OP asked the question.

I cloned and compiled it on my computer and restarted [XRMToolbox](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/) and it worked.

It requires one unmanaged solution to apply the changes to. I create one empty solution before using the tool. Remember to **Publish all customizations** from that solution when done saving from the tool.

Cheers

[Bulk Update Entity Change Tracking](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/Cobalt.XrmToolbox.EntityUpdater/)